# Mock an exception object (JUnit/Mockito)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am facing an issue testing a legacy code using JUnit/Mockito,
my method throws an exception (HandlerException) which is derived from (BaseException) which is part of our infrastructure.

```
public class HandlerException extends BaseException
```

My system-under-test is super simple:

```
public static void parse(JsonElement record) throws HandlerException
{   
    JsonElement element = record.getAsJsonObject().get(ID_TAG); 
    if(element == null) {
        throw new HandlerException("Failed to find Id ...");
    }
    ...
}
```

And also the test itself

```
@Test (expected=HandlerException.class)
public void testParseg() throws HandlerException {
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse("{}");
    Parser.parse(jsonElement);
}
```

The problem is with BaseException. It is a complex class and depends on an initialization. Without initializing it BaseException throws an exception in its constructor :( which in turn causes StackOverflowException.

Is it possible to Mock BaseException or HandlerException in any way to avoid this initialization keeping my test simple?

Comment: Could you provide the BaseException constructor ? If it is doing something "hard" to mock, then why not simplify the BaseException ?

Comment: Well, it's hard to mock stuff that you create inside your unit via "new ...". Of course there's always the possibility of adding a factory for that, but honestly, I doubt that this is a good solution here. I agree with NoDataFound, please provide the problematic code, I would also guess the problem is there.

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely there. But BaseException is an infrastructure code I am forced to use and cannot modify. I will have to find a way around this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to my issue was using PowerMockito

First I use @PrepareForTest on my system-under-test (Parser.class)

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Parser.class})
```

Then I mocked the HandlerExeption class using PowerMockito.whenNew

```
@Mock
HandlerException handlerExceptionMock;

@Before 
public void setup() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(HandlerException.class)
        .withAnyArguments().thenReturn(handlerExceptionMock);
}

@Test (expected=HandlerException.class)
public void testParseg() throws HandlerException {
    JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse("{}");
    Parser.parse(jsonElement);
}
```

This way BaseException was not constructed and my test passed without the need to initialize it.

Note: I am aware that this is not the best practice, however, in my case, I had to since I cannot edit BaseException.